# Relating $G_0(R/fR)$ and $\oplus_{P\in V(f)} G_0(R/P)$?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, homological-algebra, abelian-categories, algebraic-k-theory

For a Commutative Noetherian ring $R$, let $G_0(R)$ denote the Grothendieck group of the abelian category of finitely generated $R$-modules i.e. it is the abelian group generated by the isomorphism classes of finitely generated $R$-modules subject to the relation : $[M]=[M_1]+[M_2]$ if there is a short exact sequence of $R$-modules $0\to M_1\to M\to M_2\to 0$.

Now consider a non-zero element $0\ne f\in R$ in a commutative Noetherian ring. Let $R_f$ be the localization of $R$ at the multiplicative set $\{f^n: n\ge 0\}$ i.e. $R_f\cong R[1/f]\cong R[X]/(fX-1)$

Then, we have two canonical exact sequences namely $G_0(R/fR)\to G_0(R)\to G_0(R_f)\to 0$ (as in Chapter II,  Exercise 6.10 part (c) of Hartshorne) and also we have an exact sequence

$$\oplus_{P\in V(f)} G_0(R/P)\to G_0(R)\to G_0(R_f)\to 0$$ (for example see  Lemma 28(Localization Lemma), page 37, [https://home.adelphi.edu/~bstone/commalg-notes/commalg-3/algebra-notes-iii.pdf](https://home.adelphi.edu/%7Ebstone/commalg-notes/commalg-3/algebra-notes-iii.pdf) )

This raises the natural question: What is the connection between $G_0(R/fR)$ and $\oplus_{P\in V(f)} G_0(R/P)$ ?

Apart from the fact that for every $P\in V(f)$, there is a map  $G_0(R/P)\to G_0(R/fR)$
induced by restriction of scalars , nothing else comes to my mind.

Please help.

Comment: As you may have realized, one has a natural surjection $\oplus G_0(A/P)\to G_0(A)$, where $P$ ranges over the minimal primes of the Noetherian ring $A$.

Comment: @Mohan: I do realize that ...

Comment: If so what other connection are you looking for? I believe in general the map may not be injective.